# IServiceProvider IElementBehaviorFactory not queried until an unhandled JavaScript error is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I'm providing a custom namespace and binary behaviour to a .net WebBrowser control, and it works just fine under specific circumstances.  Using the following code, the breakpoints (marked with `●`) all hit and my namespace is properly implemented complete with the behaviour:

```
int IServiceProvider.QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject)
{
    int hr = Native.E_NOINTERFACE;
    ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero;

    if (riid == IidClsid.IID_IElementBehaviorFactory)
    {
        // Returning S_OK tells the html host to query for our IHostBehaviorInit.
●       hr = Native.S_OK;
    }
    else if (riid == IidClsid.IID_IHostBehaviorInit)
    {
        ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(IHostBehaviorInit));
●       hr = Native.S_OK;
    }
    else if (guidService == IidClsid.IID_IInternetSecurityManager)
    {
        ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(IInternetSecurityManager));
●       hr = Native.S_OK;
    }
    return hr;
}
```

However, the first and second breakpoint only hit because of a script error in the test page.  If I fix the error or suppress errors, the breakpoints never hit.  For example, the following code prevents my namespace and behaviour from ever being registered:

```
WebBrowser.Document.Window.Error += OnWebBrowserDocumentWindowError;
```

```
public void OnWebBrowserDocumentWindowError (object sender, IHTMLEventObj e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This is what the MSDN [documentation for IHostBehaviorInit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> MSHTML calls the host application's `IServiceProvider::QueryService` to request the `IElementBehaviorFactory` interface, and requests the host for the `IHostBehaviorInit` interface. If the `IHostBehaviorInit` interface is available, MSHTML calls the `IHostBehaviorInit::PopulateNamespaceTable` method. The host application can then query MSHTML for the `IElementNamespaceTable` interface and use the `IElementNamespaceTable::AddNamespace` method to append additional namespaces to the namespace table.

I've noticed that, if I click on a `<select>` to open the drop-down list, the first and second breakpoints hit all of a sudden.  It's really strange behaviour, can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: What's the IE version and what's value of `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`, if any? Have you tried disabling `FEATURE_BEHAVIORS` (setting it to `0`)?

Comment: @Noseratio: IE version is 10, but the document mode is IE 7.  `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` is set to `7000` for this application (for compatibility reasons).  `FEATURE_BEHAVIORS` is set to `1` (the default), but changing it to `0` makes no difference.

Comment: Andy, you may want to report this to Microsoft as a bug, although it probably won't be addressed. They're deprecating binary behaviors since IE10, the support for it is even worse in IE11.

Comment: @Noseratio: Thanks for your help again.  Do binary behaviours work at all in IE 10 and 11?

Comment: No problem, I wish I could help better. They still do work when `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` is set to IE9 and lower, and when the [page document mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275(v=vs.85).aspx) is Quirk. I wouldn't rely upon that they will continue to work in (say) IE12.

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer the question directly, but it's too lengthy for a simple comment.

Why do you compare `riid` rather than `guidService` in the first two cases? Looks like a bug to me, use `guidService` instead.

Further, once you've determined the service being requested, you should not be using `Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject`, because `riid` and `guidService` may differ. Instead, use `Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject` and `Marshal.QueryInterface`:

```
IntPtr unk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(this);
try
{
    return Marshal.QueryInterface(unk, ref riid, out ppvObject);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.Release(unk);
}
```

Also, **the way you implement your `IServiceProvider` may affect how MSHTML picks it up**. I suggest you use [`IProfferService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this. I have a full-fledged example of how to use `IProfferService` with `WebBrowser` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19395092/1768303).

Comment: +1, thanks, I've made the changes you recommended.  I was playing around with the `riid`/`guidService` vars and forgot to change them back before asking this question.

Comment: interesting, I'll check that out when I get a chance and get back to you.

Comment: Well, it didn't solve the problem, but your answer was very helpful.  No sense letting the bounty points go to waste :-)