# Sending Authentication data from Embedded WebBrowser Control

Tags: visual-c++, network-programming, webbrowser-control, socks

I am developing Embedded WebBrowser and I wanted to implement Socks proxy. Since, windows IE does not support Socks5, I thought of implementing Socks4 proxy with authentication. But now I am facing the problem of sending the authentication data to the server from WebBrowser Control.

Is there anyway I can send username/password from WebBrowser Control. I tried to look in MSDN library but did not found any function or API. There is page for [HTTP Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384220(v=vs.85).aspx) in which proxy authentication has been mentioned. I tried to implement it but failed.

Has anyone has implemented this approach?Any hint or idea will be really helpful.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18619110/1768303) what you're looking for?

Comment: I have already tried and implemented `IAuthenticate` and it is not sending the credentials. It is not even calling the the `Authenticate` function. I was thinking if I can sending a custom data to the server. Or any other way.

Comment: Could be a bug in your implementation. It [still works](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19395092/1768303) for me, for `IAuthenticateEx` too (which you'd need to implement to watch for `AUTHENTICATEF_PROXY` flag).

Comment: But I guess it only works when one sends the http request to a HTTP proxy server and not for the SOCKS connection request. Because I have developed SOCKS server and in order to connect with it username/password is supposed to be provide right after the SOCKS connection steps completes. I guess I have to find an alternative for this.

Comment: You might be right, I haven't tried it against a SOCKS proxy.