# C# Webbrowser Control Smartcard Login

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, smartcard, pki, autologin

I'd like to automatically login to a website that forces me to select a x509 certificate and provide a smartcard PIN to extract the private key information. What should I do to avoid the popup from appearing and instead provide the private key information to the webbrowser control for a seemless login? It is a .NET 4.5 Windows application using the standard webbrowser control.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** It seems to me as if setting the **INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_SELECT_CLIENT_CERT** option via the **InternetSetOption** function would do the trick. Does anybody know how to fit a **X509Certificate2** Object to the **InternetSetOption** signature?

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(
    IntPtr hInternet,
    int dwOption,
    IntPtr lpBuffer,
    int lpdwBufferLength);
```

Comment: It depends on the website... what is it? You can use javascript to invoke the sign in. This is done using ObjectForScripting. Can you read the smartcard pin already?

Comment: Hi Leonardo, there are 2 Websites, both are Angular web apps. One backend is made of Node.JS, one is IIS as far as I can tell. I don't know how to use your hint. If I navigate to the website I am asked for the PIN, how can I interfere this process to automatically login?

Comment: @stev-e, I'm not sure if it's going to work with x509 /w PIN, but have a look at `IAuthenticate`. I have a related post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19395092/1768303).

Comment: [this](https://jiangsheng.net/2013/07/17/howto-ignoring-web-browser-certificate-errors-in-webbrowser-host/) might also be helpful.

Comment: the latter leads to [IHttpSecurity.OnSecurityProblem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775050(v=vs.85).aspx) with error code ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED. If I implement this interface I reach the point that I know that a cert is needed but do not see a chance to provide the cert to the webbrowser control yet. I will have a look at IAuthenticate, thanks